# Need to pull parent category and slug - only pulling daughter category

Tags: categories, slug

I am tweaking a theme for my friend, and I am using the following:

`<?php $category = get_the_category(); ?> <h3 class="omc-blog-two-cat"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); echo ('/category/'.$category[0]->slug); ?>"><?php echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></a></h3>`

This gives website.com/category/categoryslug/, displaying the daughter category slug but I also want the parent category included as well. Ideally as website.com/category/parentcategory/daughtercategory

How can I achieve this? Many thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are functions for retrieving a term/category link (i.e. URL to the term archive page) and in the case of the default `category` taxonomy, you can use [`get_category_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_link):

```html
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link( $category[0] ) ); ?>"><?php echo $category[0]->name; ?></a>
```

For custom taxonomies, you'd use [`get_term_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link).

Comment: Perfect, that is a great solution. Thanks so much for your help :)